# In React.js, I want to be able to search username without distinguishing between uppercase and lowercase letters

Tags: reactjs

I am making a system that can get json data with React and search for users by name.
I want to be able to search by firstName or lastName
I thought, but with the current code
Because it is in a state where it can not be searched unless all the uppercase and lowercase letters and the character string match
If the character string matches regardless of case
I want search to work.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students')
    .then(result => {
      setPosts(result.data.students);
      setAllPosts(result.data.students);
    })
  }, []);

  const getSearchResult = (data) => {
    setSearchKeyword(data.search)
    const result = allPosts.filter((output, index) => {
      console.log(output)
      return output.firstName.includes(data.search)||output.lastName.includes(data.search);
    });
    console.log(result)
    setPosts(result);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your data and search value in the same case (uppoerCase or lowerCase). Then compare with your search value.

You can try the below method:

Change the following line

```
return output.firstName.includes(data.search)||output.lastName.includes(data.search);
```

to this line

```
return output.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(data.search.toLowerCase())||output.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(data.search.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

Conversion to upper or lower case does provide correct case insensitive comparisons in all languages. Below are the two approaches

```
var name1 = "Sapan Prajapati";
var name2 ="SAPAN PRAJAPATI";

//convert to lowercase for case insensitive comparison
if(name1.toLowerCase().includes(name2.toLowerCase())){
    // logic goes here
}
```

OR

```
//convert to uppercase for case insensitive comparison
if(name1.toUpperCase().includes(name2.toUpperCase())){
    // logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try once by replacing your getSearchResult function.

```
const getSearchResult = (data) => {
    setSearchKeyword(data.search)
    allPosts.map(post=>{return {...post, firstName:post.firstName.toLowerCase(),lastName:post.lastName.toLowerCase()}})
    data.search=data.search.toLowerCase()
    const result = allPosts.filter((output, index) => {
      console.log(output)
      return output.firstName.includes(data.search)||output.lastName.includes(data.search);
    });
    console.log(result)
    setPosts(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make both your strings lowercase and then search for it.

```
return output.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(data.search.toLowerCase())||output.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(data.search.toLowerCase());
```

This will search regardless of the case.